# Hash password in PHP and verify with Java (PASSWORD_BCRYPT & jBcrypt)

Tags: java, php, bcrypt

I have a question regarding the hashing of password. I am using this on the webpage:

```
$pw = password_hash($_POST[password], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

After that I store this result in the database. With my Java Web Service I want to verify the password. For that I am using this method:

```
   if (BCrypt.checkpw(password, dbPwd)){
       return Response.ok("ok").build();
   }
```

`dbPwd` is the one I stored and password is the password in plain text from the first method. Unfortunately I am receiving this error code:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Invalid salt revision

### Update

I found in the internet, that there is a "bug" the Java method is using the 2y and the jBcrypt is using 2a. I tried it with 2a and it works, but how can I fix this/ make it work?

Comment: You should find a better bcrypt lib: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20541/insecure-versions-of-crypt-hashes

Comment: thank you, helps a lot. its working now. Stupid issue and I was not able to find the right answer :-)

Comment: Jeez the more I read the second answer on that link the more faith I lose in the people writing bcrypt implementations. It sounds like `2a` and `2y` are compatible, and probably `2b` as well. Just do `dbPwd[2] = 'a';` and it should be fine. `:/`

Comment: Yes they are compatible. I used the same  way you are mentioned to get it done... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging I found a newer implementation of the jBcrypt library: https://github.com/patrickfav/bcrypt

I use Scala but the concepts are essentially the same and to verify a `$2y$` hash I've created a small utility function:

```
import at.favre.lib._

  /**
    * Verifies an encrypted password against the expected value
    *
    * @link https://github.com/patrickfav/bcrypt
    * @param hash The hashed password (encypted with BCrypt version $2Y$)
    * @param password The unencrypted password string
    */
  private def verifyBcryptHash(hash: String, password: String): Boolean = {
    if (hash == null || hash.trim.isEmpty)
      false
    else
      BCrypt
        .verifyer()
        .verifyStrict(
          password.toCharArray(),
          hash.toCharArray(),
          BCrypt.Version.VERSION_2Y
        )
        .verified
  }
```